# Misunderstanding regarding applied maths lecture

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My lecturer put up on the board on one of his powerpoints the following:

Nondimensionalised equations:

It is often useful to scale variables to make them dimensionless, for example in the model:
$$\rm
\frac{dh}{dt} = k(h_1 - h)(h_2 - h)
$$
Define: $\rm H = h/h_1$ and $\rm x = kh_1t$
$$\rm
[H] = L/L = 1
\\
[x] = 1/LT \times L \times T = 1
$$
This is where I got confused. All of this makes sense to me, but then he says
$$\rm
{dH \over dx} = (1 - H)(H_2 - H),\text{ where }H_2 = h_2/h_1
$$

I'm unsure how this step has been made.

Comment: Please learn how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). You are no longer a new user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As written $H=H(t)$ is a function of $t$. If you want to express it's derivative in terms of $x$, by the chain rule $\frac{dH}{dx}=\frac{dH}{dt}\frac{dt}{dx}$. You can derive $dt/dx$ by noticing that $t=x/(kh_1)$. It follows that:

$$\frac{dH}{dx}=\left(\frac{1}{h_1}\frac{dh}{dt}\right)\left(\frac{1}{kh_1}\right).$$

Can you finish the problem from here?

Comment: Where do you get the "it follows that" from?

Comment: @SamConnell: I rewrote it, pardon the typo.

Comment: I don't understand where the (1/h1 x dh/dt) comes from. Is it because you've mistyped dH/dx as dH/dt on the LHS? And the reason is dH/dt = dh/dt x dH/dh and as H = h/h1, dH/dh = 1/h1?

Comment: Could I have some clarification please

Comment: I think your older comment refers to an older version of the answer. Is the above not clear?